# React Native - Navigator inconsistent across different methods

Tags: android, react-native

I am creating my first React Native App. I am trying to use the navigator object for navigating between different views.

In the below code snippet.
The openRecipe method written works perfectly but the goBack method throws an exception saying
**undefined is not an object(evaluating this.props.navigator)**

I haven't added any props to the Component Class, which I initially thought to be a problem, but since the OpenRecipe method works fine, I am confused on why goBack is throwing on exception which has the same method body as the openRecipe method.

If there were an issue with not including dependencies then it should have been consistent across both the methods.

Once it is sorted out,I am planning to use this.props.navigator.pop() to go back to the previous page.

```
openRecipe(data){
    this.props.navigator.push({
      id: 'RecipePage',
      name: 'Recipe',
    });
  }

  goBack(){
    Alert.alert(
                "Here Back!",
                )
    this.props.navigator.push({
      id: 'RecipePage',
      name: 'Recipe',
    });
  }



  render() {

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.row}>
          <Text style={styles.title}>Recipe</Text>

          <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.goBack}>
              <Text style={styles.title} >BACK</Text>
            </TouchableHighlight>
        </View>

        <ListView
        dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
        renderRow={(data) =>
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.openRecipe(data)}>
          <View style={styles.article_container} >
              <Text style={styles.article_title} >{data.title}</Text>

              <Image style={styles.article_img}
                  source={{uri: data.image_link}}
              />
          </View>
        </TouchableHighlight>


         }
        />

      </View>
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

If your component is implemented as an ES6 class, the `goBack` method is not automatically bound to the `this` instance of your object, which `React.createClass` does automatically. The solution is to either pass in a "fat arrow" lambda as the `onPress` prop (e.g `onPress={() => this.goBack()}`), which will bind `this` to the value it has where the lambda is defined, or to bind it explicitly with `onPress={this.goBack.bind(this)}`

To elaborate, now that I'm not on a phone keyboard...

In javascript, the value of `this` depends on the context in which a function (or method) is *called*, not where it's defined.  When a function is a property of an object (a method), *and* it's invoked as such, `this` has the value you probably expect; it's the parent object that contains the method.

```
const person = {
  name: 'Shaurya',
  sayHello() {
    return "Hi " + this.name
  }
}

person.sayHello() // -> "Hi Shaurya"
```

But if I store the `sayHello` function in a variable and call it from "outside" the object's context, the value of `this` will depend on where you're calling the function from.  If you're running at the global scope (e.g inside a global function, or at a node repl), `this` will be the global object (where language builtins like `Math` live). Unless that happens to have a `name` property, you'll get `undefined` for `this.name`:

```
let sayHi = person.sayHello
sayHi() // -> "Hi undefined"
```

You can use the `.apply` method of the `Function` type to set the value of `this` to something else temporarily:

```
sayHi.apply(person) // -> "Hi Shaurya"
sayHi.apply({name: "Yusef"}) // -> "Hi Yusef"
sayHi() // -> still "Hi undefined"
```

Or, you can use `.bind` to set the value of `this` and make it persist:

```
var sayHiToPerson = person.sayHello.bind(person)
sayHiToPerson() // -> "Hi Shaurya"
```

The "fat arrow" lambdas introduced in ES6 capture the value of `this`, and no matter where you invoke it, `this` will have the same value as it did when the lambda was defined.  That's why your second `onPress` handler works but the first one doesn't.  Inside the body of `() => this.openRecipe(data)`, `this` gets bound automatically to the value it had inside the `.render` method.  But when you just pass `this.goBack` you lose that context, and `this` has a different value when the function is invoked by the event handling system.